# Why does the CREATE PROCEDURE statement fail when I use it with IF Statement here?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, batch-file

I am trying to DROP a stored procedure if it exists and then CREATE it by doing this way:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[myStoredProc]') IS not NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.myStoredProc


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProc]
(
    @parameter1 BIT
) AS

IF @parameter1 = 1
    BEGIN
             ....
```

But it complains that :

> "CREATE PROCEDURE must be the only statement in the batch"

**Question:** How can I fix my script to overcome this?

Answer (score 17):

You need to put a `go` at the end of your first logical batch.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[myStoredProc]') IS not NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.myStoredProc
go -- you need to add the batch-terminator 'go'


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProc]
(
    @parameter1 BIT
) AS

IF @parameter1 = 1
    BEGIN
             ..
```

Comment: Worked! But why it is necessery to terminate? I mean the logic behind

Comment: @pencilCake Because the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement has to be the first statement (and only one) in a batch.

Comment: @pencilCake: Against a possible confusion as to what exactly should be included into the definition, I think. Suppose they allow you to mix procedure creation with other statements. One would then naturally expect to be allowed to put statements not only before the procedure definition, but also after it as well, as part of some object creation logic. But how could you tell where the definition ends? The global `BEGIN ... END` keywords aren't mandatory, any number of statements can follow `AS` – so, which one of them stops being part of the procedure and instead belongs to the ‘outer’ script?

Comment: @pencilCake: One other thing: you can add comments and/or any number of empty lines before `CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE`, and the parser includes them into the definition. But if there was a comment section between `CREATE PROCEDURE` and the preceding statement, how would the parser ‘know’ whether the comments belong with the previous statement or with the procedure? So, ultimately, I guess, they just ended up with the said restriction: you only define a procedure (as well as a function, a view, a trigger) in a separate batch.

Answer (score 8):

Adding **[GO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)** after your `IF` statement shows that this is the end of your first query batch.

Read more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[myStoredProc]') IS not NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.myStoredProc
GO
```

This will prevent your error from occurring.